# Spectre CSS - Opening a modal based on an id value

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, spectre.css

For this question, I will be using the [Spectre CSS framework](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/components/modals.html).

I currently have the following modal code, but plan on having multiple ones in the page:

```
<div class="modal modal-lg" id="myModalId">
    <a href="#close" class="modal-overlay" aria-label="Close"></a>
    <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="#close" class="btn btn-clear float-right" aria-label="Close"></a>
            <div class="modal-title h5">My Title</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="content">
                <!-- content here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, to open the modal I am using a specific button call to add the `active` class (which from the documentation opens the modal.

> To make a modal appear, add the active class to the modal container.

But this is quite an inefficient way to handle what will be 20+ modals. How can I use jQuery to target specific modals to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following two jQuery functions for opening and closing modals:

```
$(document).delegate('.modal-toggle', 'click', function(e) {
    var modal = $(this).attr('data-modal');

    $(modal).addClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).delegate('.modal-close', 'click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.modal').removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This works with the following HTML for use with Spectre CSS:

```
<!-- Button -->
<button class="btn btn-primary modal-toggle" data-modal="#myModalId">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModalId">
    <a class="modal-overlay modal-close" aria-label="Close"></a>
    <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="btn btn-clear close-modal float-right modal-close" aria-label="Close"></a>
            <div class="modal-title h5">My Title</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```